# Javascript jquery locks up in Safari (only)

Tags: javascript, safari

I've created a website which uses javascript to run a jquery gallery viewer. A problem surfaces when using the gallery in Safari only (but not with Chrome, Firefox, etc).

At first, the gallery runs smoothly. But if you click through enough pictures (on a single gallery page, or over several pages containing different galleries) eventually the gallery script stops working. At that point, all of the gallery functions stop, even if you visit a different gallery on a different page in the website. Neither refreshing the page, a hard refresh, clearing the cache, visiting a different gallery/page, or closing the tab and re-opening in a new tab, brings back the functionality. The only way to get it working again is to close the Safari window, open a new window, and go to the page again. (I wonder what the browsing session has to do with this?)

I have tried using the console, and tried using Firebug Lite, to diagnose the problem, without success. No errors appear in the console when the script stops working; the controls just stop working.

I can duplicate the problem reliably on different machines running Safari (most easily by repeatedly and quickly cycling through the pictures in a gallery over and over till it locks up). I cannot duplicate the problem using any other browser.

Any help in figuring out what's wrong, or even suggestions of how to troubleshoot the problem, would be greatly appreciated!

The galleries can be found here:

http://www.gailcohenphotography.com/galleries.html

Many thanks,
- Paul

Comment: sounds like a memory management problem to me

Comment: or excessive re-binding of event handlers, without unbinding existing ones.

Comment: Works fine for me, but I'm using Safari on a Mac. I must have clicked over a hundred times trying to get the gallery to lock up.

Comment: @Rick Viscomi - how do I check, and fix if this is the case?

Comment: @Alnitak - how do I check this, and fix if it is the case?

Comment: @EliteOctagon - thanks for trying. I'm using a Mac too, and have no trouble locking it up, over and over. Hmmm... (Using Safari 5.9.1)

Comment: After your comment I decided to count: Locks up for me at between 80 and 110 clicks, usually.